# Multivariable calculus, differential equations : does one solution exist? If yes, which

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I got this question on a homeowork

$$
y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}-2x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2xy^4
$$

with the additional condition that $f(1,y)=2y^4$. They gave us the lead to perform the variable substitution

$$
u=xy^2, v=y.
$$

When I perform the proposed substitution I can see that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y }=\frac{\partial f}{\partial v }$ but I do not know how to interpret $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x }$ with the respect to $u$. I am not sure where to start at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$u=xy^2, v=y\implies x=\frac u{v^2},y=v$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y }=\frac{\partial f}{\partial v }+\frac{\partial f}{\partial u }\cdot 2xy$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x }=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u }\cdot y^2$$
$$y\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial v }+\frac{\partial f}{\partial u }\cdot 2xy\right)-2x\frac{\partial f}{\partial u }\cdot y^2=2xy^4$$
$$v\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial v }+\frac{\partial f}{\partial u }\cdot 2\frac uv\right)-2\frac u{v^2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial u }\cdot v^2=2uv^2$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial v }=2uv$$
$$f=uv^2+\phi (u)=xy^4+\phi(xy^2)$$
$$y^4+\phi(y^2)=2y^4\implies\phi(y)=y^2$$
$$f(x,y)=xy^4+x^2y^4$$

Comment: Thank you! However I do not follow the part 

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\cdot 2xy$$.

How did you get to that?

Comment: Never mind, I realized you used the chain rule. Thank you very much!

Comment: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$